# How to interpret Rackspace server diagnostics?

Tags: web-server, cloud, rackspace

We've been having some trouble lately with our site timing out during times of high traffic.

We're working on a number of things to resolve it.  During this process I came across our server diagnostics page on Rackspace, and it has the following line:

```
The host server's load is: 0.08 0.08 0.03 1/204 2437
```

I couldn't find an explanation on their site or Google.  Can anyone explain what these numbers mean? For I am a lowly programmer.

Much appreciated,

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the server's CPU load average for 1, 5, and 15 minutes.  Rather than rewriting the explanation, wikipedia has a pretty good explanation of it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)).  I'm not sure what the 1/204 and 2437 values are though, you might have to ask Rackspace, unless somebody else has a good idea of them.

Answer (score 1):

Those statistics are pulled straight from /proc/loadavg. Here are the definitions for those last two figures:

> The fourth field consists of two numbers separated by a slash (/). The first of these is the number of currently executing kernel scheduling entities (processes, threads); this will be less than or equal to the number of CPUs. The value after the slash is the number of kernel scheduling entities that currently exist on the system. The fifth field is the PID of the process that was most recently created on the system. [[source]](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)